# Phonegap application in android 4.0.3 with Jquery mobile is not displaying content

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am cretaing a Phonegap appllication. I am using jquerymobile for my page loadings and transitions. The application is working fine in all versions of android except for ICS 4.0.3.

After loading the page, some of the elements in the page are visible for a second and they are invisible.

The elements that are invisible are mostly  tag,  and div's with data-role="button".

i am also getting an error like below:

```
couldn't load the vertex shader!

call to OpenGL ES API with no current context
```

I have already added `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

Can someone let me know why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason for my problem at a later point.

I am using  `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden` for smoother animations and it is the reason why my page is not displayed properly in ICS.

When i removed that from my css, the application is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can run the pages on Google Chrome and just observe the console for errors(if there are any). This is because if the pages built in phonegap, run properly on Chrome browser then they will run fine on emulator or actual device. You can activate the **console** by pressing the F12 key.

Also you can try using **`rel="external"`** at the end of `<data role=button>` like 
`<data role=button.....rel=external>`. It may help to open the pages properly.

Comment: running in Chrome does not guarantee proper execution on devices.

Comment: @dharga : If you run the page in Chrome and it is error free, then on device it will run properly as I have done this actually. There are very few chances to break something on devices that was previously running fine on Chrome.